# Filling a column of a CSV file with a value in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a CSV file where in the 'Gender' column some of the fields are missing. So I  need to autofill them using the fillna() function using python. I am giving a condition that if the ApplicantIncome is greater than 20000, then the fields must be updated with the 'Male' tag in 'Gender' column. The code for the same is pasted below and also the error associated with that error. So, can anyone please help me out in solving the error

> if data['ApplicantIncome'] >= 20000:
>       data['Gender'].fillna(data['Gender'] == 'Male',inplace=True)

The error is as below:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-97-19fee6c4a819> in <module>
----> 1 if data['ApplicantIncome'] >= 20000:
      2     data['Gender'].fillna(data['Gender'] == 'Male',inplace=True)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in __nonzero__(self)
   1574         raise ValueError("The truth value of a {0} is ambiguous. "
   1575                          "Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."
-> 1576                          .format(self.__class__.__name__))
   1577 
   1578     __bool__ = __nonzero__

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Comment: @PatrickArtner - What you said is absolutely true. But according to my dataset when I plot a boxplot by Gender, all the income holders above 20000 are men. So that's the only reason why I have used this as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You can [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mask.html) your series:

```
df['Gender'] = df['Gender'].mask(df['Income'] >= 20000, df['Gender'].fillna('Male'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`np.where()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data['Gender']=np.where(data['ApplicantIncome']>= 20000,data['Gender'].fillna('Male'),data['Gender'])
```

Comment: @Vivek Please dont forget to accept the answer(click on the tick mark) if it helped you. Thanks

Comment: Yes I did right after I checked whether its working or not, but its displaying a message as follows: 

Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.

Comment: @Vivek : Check this link and you will learn how to do it. :)  [How does accepting an answer work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)